# Trying to left align labels

Tags: html, css

I have following html and my goal is to align the labels for the text boxes so that they are aligned with left edges of their text boxes. Right now they are center aligned due to css on outermost div. Also, I do not want to lose the center alignment of the outermost div.

I tried setting `text-align:left` for each of the `labels` but it did nothing.

A demo for this question  is at following URL: [Demo](http://js.do/sun21170/78304)

**Question** : What css I need to use to left align the labels?

[image: Left Align Labels with textboxes]

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px; width: 800px;">
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="txtName">Full Name</label><br>
      <input id="txtName" type="text" style="width:80%" /><br>
      <label for="txtCity">City</label><br>
      <input id="txtCity" type="text" style="width:80%" /><br>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

1. `display: block` for `label` as it is an inline element.
2. You haven't closed `<div>` correctly.
3. Remove the `<br>` and update this way:

See the updated snippet, that **works**:

```css
label {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  text-indent: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px; width: 800px;">
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="txtName">Full Name</label>
      <input id="txtName" type="text" style="width:80%" /><br>
      <label for="txtCity">City</label>
      <input id="txtCity" type="text" style="width:80%" /><br>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: The labels are left aligned but not with the left edge of the text boxes. I need them left aligned with the left edges of text boxes as mentioned in my OP.

Comment: @Sunil In that case, see the updated answer in a min.

Comment: @Sunil `text-indent: 10%;` will fix it for you. `:)`

Comment: I edited my code snippet since it had a mismatched div

Comment: @Sunil The explanation for it is: The `input` is `80%` so, it has `10%` in the each of the side. So, if we indent `10%` for the `label`, it aligns with the `input`. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but it gives a strange looking layout. Try it at http://js.do/sun21170/78306.

Comment: @Sunil That's expected one... What do you wanna achieve then? The margins on the top and bottom?

Comment: @Parveen, Thanks for the quick solution. I also found that using `margin-left:10%` worked instead of `text-indent:10%`. Demo is here: http://js.do/sun21170/78309